# Positioning element on right side of table header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'd like to have a little handle on the right side of my tables that can be used for resizing the column. I've got some relatively clean CSS and markup that seems to do the trick ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/NVYJK/)):

#### HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span class=resize> </span>
        <div class=label>
          Column 1
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span class=resize> </span>
        <div class=label>
          Column 2
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

#### CSS:

```
table thead th {
  position: relative;
}

table thead th .resize {
  width: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

This seems to work great in WebKit and IE 8, but fail miserably in Firefox.

How do I make this work in Firefox as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a container `div` inside your `th` element and use `position: relative;` on the container `div`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NVYJK/2/)

Explanation: The effect of `position: relative` on table elements is undefined in [CSS 2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position), so in order to get your thing work, use a wrapping div inside your `th` element and assign `position: relative;` to that `div`

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
          <div class="container">
        <span class="resize"> </span>
        <div class="label">
          Column 1
        </div>
          </div>
      </th>
      <th>
          <div class="container">
        <span class="resize"> </span>
        <div class="label">
          Column 2
        </div>
           </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table thead th {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
position: relative;
}

table thead th span.resize {
  width: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

Comment: so i see line in the spec about "The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, ... table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined", and i'm curious, is a <th> element considered "table-header-group"? or "table-cell"?

Comment: `th` are used for defining table headers generally they are rendered bold by browser ofcourse if you don't apply your styles

Comment: yeah i know that, but the wording of the spec doesn't really tell me what elements are included in the 'undefined' behavior, it just tells me table-header-group elements are. so my question is whether table-header-group elements include `<th>`'s

Answer (score 0):

the quick answer seems to be just wrapping the contents of the header cell in a div:

#### HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class=wrapper>
          <span class=resize> </span>
          <div class=label>
            Column 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class=wrapper>
          <span class=resize> </span>
          <div class=label>
            Column 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
table thead th .wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

table thead th .resize {
  width: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NVYJK/1/